# Yarn dev command loads and shows errors

Tags: sqlite, electron, yarnpkg, openai-whisper

Im trying to launch Stage- Whisper (https://github.com/Stage-Whisper/Stage-Whisper)
The Programm is installed but when i put the Audio file in it, it doesnt load further or gives any respond.

Those are the errors which i get after the "yarn dev" command:

```
-intern:electron administrator$ yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.20
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ concurrently --names "VITE,ELECTRON" -c "bgBlue.bold,bgGreen.bold" "yarn dev:vite" " yarn dev:electron"
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ vite
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ npm run build:electron && electron .
[ELECTRON] 
[ELECTRON] > stagewhisper@0.1.0 build:electron
[ELECTRON] > tsc -p electron
[ELECTRON] 
[VITE] 
[VITE]   VITE v3.1.6  ready in 3445 ms
[VITE] 
[VITE]   ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:3000/
[VITE]   ➜  Network: use --host to expose
[ELECTRON] Starting Electron...
[ELECTRON] /Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/main
[ELECTRON] Initializing Database
[ELECTRON] Database initialized
[ELECTRON] Creating tables...
[ELECTRON] Creating settings table...
[ELECTRON] Creating entries table...
[ELECTRON] Creating transcriptions table...
[ELECTRON] Creating lines table...
[ELECTRON] queryDatabase.ts: Loading...
[ELECTRON] QueryDatabase.ts: loaded
[ELECTRON] (node:32684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The module '/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node'
[ELECTRON] was compiled against a different Node.js version using
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 101. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
[ELECTRON] the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
[ELECTRON]     at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1199:18)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
[ELECTRON]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
[ELECTRON]     at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13331)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
[ELECTRON]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
[ELECTRON]     at bindings (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
[ELECTRON]     at new Database (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:48:64)
[ELECTRON] (Use `Electron --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[ELECTRON] (node:32684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 6)
[ELECTRON] (node:32684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The module '/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node'
[ELECTRON] was compiled against a different Node.js version using
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 101. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
[ELECTRON] the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
[ELECTRON]     at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1199:18)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
[ELECTRON]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
[ELECTRON]     at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13331)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
[ELECTRON]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
[ELECTRON]     at bindings (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
[ELECTRON]     at new Database (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:48:64)
[ELECTRON] (node:32684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 12)
[ELECTRON] Initializing app
[ELECTRON] Store is at: /Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/stagewhisper/store
[ELECTRON] ~I'm a mac~
[VITE] Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
[VITE]   npx browserslist@latest --update-db
[VITE]   Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
[ELECTRON] (node:32684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The module '/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node'
[ELECTRON] was compiled against a different Node.js version using
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 101. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
[ELECTRON] the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
[ELECTRON]     at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1199:18)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
[ELECTRON]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
[ELECTRON]     at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13331)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
[ELECTRON]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
[ELECTRON]     at bindings (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
[ELECTRON]     at new Database (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:48:64)
[ELECTRON] (node:32684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 18)
[ELECTRON] (node:32684) ExtensionLoadWarning: Warnings loading extension at /Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/stagewhisper/extensions/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd:
[ELECTRON]   Permission 'notifications' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.
[ELECTRON]   Permission 'contextMenus' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.
[ELECTRON] 
[ELECTRON] Added Extension:  Redux DevTools
[ELECTRON] (node:32684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The module '/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node'
[ELECTRON] was compiled against a different Node.js version using
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 101. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
[ELECTRON] the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
[ELECTRON]     at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1199:18)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
[ELECTRON]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
[ELECTRON]     at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13331)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
[ELECTRON]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
[ELECTRON]     at bindings (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
[ELECTRON]     at new Database (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:48:64)
[ELECTRON] (node:32684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 24)
[ELECTRON] Error occurred in handler for 'getAllEntries': Error: The module '/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node'
[ELECTRON] was compiled against a different Node.js version using
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 101. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
[ELECTRON] the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
[ELECTRON]     at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1199:18)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
[ELECTRON]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
[ELECTRON]     at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13331)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
[ELECTRON]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
[ELECTRON]     at bindings (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
[ELECTRON]     at new Database (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:48:64) {
[ELECTRON]   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
[ELECTRON] }
[ELECTRON] Error occurred in handler for 'getAllEntries': Error: The module '/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node'
[ELECTRON] was compiled against a different Node.js version using
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
[ELECTRON] NODE_MODULE_VERSION 101. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
[ELECTRON] the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
[ELECTRON]     at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1199:18)
[ELECTRON]     at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:1800)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
[ELECTRON]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
[ELECTRON]     at Function.c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13331)
[ELECTRON]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
[ELECTRON]     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
[ELECTRON]     at bindings (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
[ELECTRON]     at new Database (/Users/administrator/Desktop/Stage-Whisper/electron/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:48:64) {
[ELECTRON]   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
[ELECTRON] }
```

I tried to rebuild npm and yarn (npm rebuild and yarn rebuild), but so far i still get the same errors.